# Can't set HTTP-Only cookie from Java backend to NextJS app

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-security, next.js

I'm having a hard time with cookies. I'm sending and Http-Only cookie in the response when my NextJS app does a /login request to my backend, I thought that it was going to be saved on the Cookie storage and it would be available on req.headers.cookie on ServerSideProps on my NextJS app, but my cookies are never set, even though they appear in the /login response from my backend.

I do a request to my Gateway Microservice which then redirects it to my Security microservice, in that security microservice I write the cookies like this and save a JWT in it:

```
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Authentication", token);
        cookie.setMaxAge(28800);
        cookie.setSecure(false); //TODO: Change this to false or true depending on dev or prod
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);

        response.addCookie(cookie);
        response.addHeader(AUTH_HEADER_KEY, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
```

Then the response from my backend when my frontend does a /login POST request is like this:

[image]

But is never saved in storage in my browser as shown by this:

[image]

And neither when requesting them on my ServerSideProps Next function:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  locale,
  req,
}) => {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  console.log('Cookies: ', cookies);
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale ? locale : 'es', ['dashboard'])),
    },
  };
};
```

My request for /login looks like this on the frontend:

```
const loginUserMutation = useMutation(
    ({ email, password }: UserLogin) => {
      return axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_DOMAIN_URL + '/login', {
        email,
        password,
      });
    },
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        const loggedUser: LoggedUser = {
          role: data.data.role,
          email: data.data.email,
          token: data.headers.authorization,
        };
        saveUserInContext(loggedUser);
        router.push('/');
      },
    }
  );
```

What else can I do? My NextJS app is on localhost:3000 and my gateway is on localhost:4010 and my security microservice is on localhost:4020

EDIT:

Found out that if in my CORS Configuration I add this lines it will work and also by using allowCredentials on my frontend. BUT beware, my Spring Cloud Gateway microservice is thrashing my headers, so I have to still look into it, but if you got this same problem try using directly your endpoint.

```
 @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Set-Cookie"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Set-Cookie` to the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

Comment: It partly worked, I had to add some allowedOrigins and allowCredentials in order to work, but somehow my Spring Gateway is trashing my headers. Thanks!

Comment: Since this is a cross-origin request, there should be an OPTIONS call sent (by the browser) before this call. If you look at the response of that, it'll be easy to troubleshoot issues like these.

Comment: Exactly, it is failling starting on the OPTIONS, I think it's because I do a DedupeResponseHeaders in my Gateway for the origin headers and somehow I'm probably discarding the ones that come from my Spring Security microservice, instead of discarding the duped one from the Gateway.